# INDEX MATCH, VLOOKUP, OR SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel

I have 2 files shown below.

One file contains Transaction Dates, Vehicle Number, and VIN number.

The second file contains Vehicle Number, Pickup Date, Return Date, and VIN number.

I'm trying to create a formula that will return the correct VIN number for the vehicle used based on the transaction date.  The transaction date occurs between the pickup date and the return date.

The issue is I have several VIN numbers for the same vehicle number so I need the vin number for the vehicle used when the transaction took place.

In the sample below you will see the transaction date of 5/10/2018 on the first line item of my first file.

I need to return the correct vin number which is row 730 from my second file.

[image: Data]

Comment: I would concatenate your vin number with date to create a unique code. Using this you'll be able to vlookup vin on specific date.

Comment: what about the dates that fall in between the pickup date and return date?

Comment: In first file, you concatenate VIN and transact date. In second file, you concat VIN number and pick up date (only). This is assuming the transact date is the same as pick up date. Then you can vlookup one table to the other.

Comment: Pickup Date is not the same as transaction date.  Pickup date is when vehicle was first used and return date is when vehicle was last used.

Comment: What happens if more than one vehicle with matching dates?#

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image:

[image]

You see that vehicle DMI2-F16 with transaction date 5/10/2018 is unique in both spreadsheets.

So, you need to create a column:

(1) in first file, between Vehicle and VIN

(2) in second file, between Return and VIN.

This column will be:

(1) `=CONCATENATE(D2,AT2)`, and drag down to encompass all data.

(2) `=CONCATENATE(B2,F2)`, and drag down to encompass all data.

Then you can lookup in AU:

```
=VLOOKUP([concatenated field], [range in other file - something like this file!F:H], 2, 0)
```

This will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Oday, I may have to do that.  Its just that my vehicle file has 1117 rows so I would have to concatenate lots of data.

Comment: When you do concatenate on first row of data, you just drag down the formula and it will do it for you.. You do not have to do it one by one.

Comment: Oday, I was able to find a formula that worked! =INDEX(VEHICLESALLTIME!$E$2:$E$5,MATCH(1,INDEX((VEHICLESALLTIME!$B$2:$B$5=Sheet1!B2)*(INT(VEHICLESALLTIME!$C$2:$C$5)<=Sheet1!A2)*(INT(VEHICLESALLTIME!$D$2:$D$5)>=Sheet1!A2),,),0),1)